# AWS Glue issue with double quote and commas

Tags: hadoop, hive, presto, amazon-athena, aws-glue

I have this CSV file:

```
reference,address
V7T452F4H9,"12410 W 62TH ST, AA D"
```

The following options are being used in the table definition

```
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'quoteChar'='\"', 
  'separatorChar'=',')
```

but it still won't recognize the double quotes in the data, and that comma in the double quote fiel is messing up the data. When I run the Athena query, the result looks like this

```
reference     address
V7T452F4H9    "12410 W 62TH ST
```

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: In case it saves someone else a bunch of searching, this is how I fixed it for my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57498330/specify-a-serde-serialization-lib-with-aws-glue-crawler

Including the first comment to delete fields before re-running

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look like you also need to add `escapeChar`. [AWS Athena docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/csv.html) shows this example:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE myopencsvtable (
   col1 string,
   col2 string,
   col3 string,
   col4 string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   'separatorChar' = ',',
   'quoteChar' = '\"',
   'escapeChar' = '\\'
   )
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 's3://location/of/csv/';
```

Answer (score 12):

I do this to solve:

1 - Create a Crawler that doesn't overwrite the target table properties, I used boto3 for this but it can be created in AWS console too, by doing this (change the xxx-var):

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('glue')

response = client.create_crawler(
    Name='xxx-Crawler-Name',
    Role='xxx-Put-here-your-rol',
    DatabaseName='xxx-databaseName',
    Description='xxx-Crawler description if u need it',
    Targets={
        'S3Targets': [
            {
                'Path': 's3://xxx-Path-to-s3/',
                'Exclusions': [
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
    SchemaChangePolicy={
        'UpdateBehavior': 'LOG',
        'DeleteBehavior': 'LOG'
    },
    Configuration='{ \
        "Version": 1.0, \
        "CrawlerOutput": { \
            "Partitions": {"AddOrUpdateBehavior": "InheritFromTable" \
            }, \
            "Tables": {"AddOrUpdateBehavior": "MergeNewColumns" } \
        }  \
    }'
)

# run the crawler
response = client.start_crawler(
    Name='xxx-Crawler-Name'
)
```

2 - Edit the serialization lib, I do this in AWS Console like say this post (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/glue-best-practices.html#schema-csv-quotes)
just change this:

[image: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde]

3 - Run Crawler again. Run the crawler as always do:

[image: Using AWS Console]

4 - That's it, your 2nd run should not change any data in the table, it's just for testing that it's works ¯\*(ツ)*/¯.

Comment: Another useful link I came across --> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/csv-serde.html