# AWS Glue crawler drop unused columns

Tags: amazon-web-services, schema, aws-glue, amazon-athena

The crawler **1st crawl** will create a table schema, some time it not detect `"` & `,` correctly and break the data row.

[image: break schema]

I fix it by [updating the table Serde serialization lib](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/glue-best-practices.html#schema-csv-quotes).

But now I have a problem, the additional columns that created in **1st crawl** still remain, even I re-run the crawler. It has thousands of columns, very annoying.

[image]

Is it possible to remove unnecessary columns *(`col30`, `col31`, `col32`, ... `col3034`)* on **2nd crawl**?

Comment: Can you try re-creating a new crawler and run it with the updated serde properties? Also drop the existing table before you re-run the new crawler.

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy [Cannot set serde properties in crawler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57498330/specify-a-serde-serialization-lib-with-aws-glue-crawler/63398790#63398790)

Comment: have you tried custom classifier  ? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/custom-classifier.html

Comment: tried already, seems not working also