# AWS Glue cannot detect correct schema from CSV

Tags: csv, etl, aws-glue, amazon-athena, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have a csv with the current structure:

- **name, path, date**
- aurora, Chicago, 20200130
- mark, "Syracuse, 2365", 2020131

The result table in Glue looks like:

- **name, path, date**
- aurora, Chicago, 20200130
- mark, Syracuse, 2365

I tried to build a classifier for CSV and add it to the Crawler but, as quotes are present only in some rows, it doesn't help Glue to find the right schema, that would be:

- **name, path, date**
- aurora | Chicago | 20200130
- mark | Syracuse, 2365 | 2020131

Any idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS Glue issue with double quote and commas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50354123/aws-glue-issue-with-double-quote-and-commas)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [OpenCSV SerDe](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/csv.html) for this.

Your CREATE TABLE query will look like this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testtimestamp1(
 `profile_id` string,
 `creationdate` date,
 `creationdatetime` timestamp
 )
 ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
 LOCATION 's3://<location>'
```

Create the table in Athena using the above query (instead of using Glue)

Once the table is created, use `MSCK REPAIR TABLE <table_name>`, to actually load the partitions.